# Why doesn't GHC type checker like one of the two functions that look almost the same?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to solve one of the chapter exercise in Chapter 11, "Algebraic Datatypes" in [Haskell Book](http://haskellbook.com/). But I'm stuck with a type error, can't understand why a very similar function works, whereas another doesn't.

This is how I start:

```
type Digit = Char

type Presses = Int

data DaPhone =
  DaPhone [(Char, Digit, Presses)]
  deriving Show

myPhone :: DaPhone
myPhone =
  DaPhone [('a', '2', 1), ('b', '2', 2), ('c', '2', 3)]

reverseTaps :: DaPhone -> Char -> [(Digit, Presses)]
reverseTaps aPhone aChar = foldr f [] aPhone
  where f (c, d, p)
          | c == aChar = ((d, p):)
        f _         = id
```

and get the following error:

```
daPhone.hs:29:39: Couldn't match expected type ‘t0 (Char, Digit, Presses)’ …
                with actual type ‘DaPhone’
    In the third argument of ‘foldr’, namely ‘aPhone’
    In the expression: foldr f [] aPhone
Compilation failed.
```

But if I try almost the same function with almost the same type, such as the following:

```
myList :: [(Char, Char, Int)]
myList = [('a', '2', 1), ('b', '2', 2), ('c', '2', 3)]

myFunction :: [(Char, Char, Int)] -> Char -> [(Char, Int)]
myFunction aList aChar = foldr f [] aList
  where f (c, d, p)
          | c == aChar = ((d,p):)
        f _           = id
```

It compiles and works as expected:

```
λ> myFunction myList 'a'
[('2',1)]
λ> myFunction myList 'b'
[('2',2)]
λ> myFunction myList 'c'
[('2',3)]
```

So, why do I get type error in `reverseTaps`, that is very similar to `myFunction`? (I guess it is about the definition of DaPhone, meaning maybe I need to do more pattern patching in `foldr`, etc., but I couldn't find out exactly how).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like you just need

```
myFunction (DaPhone aList) aChar = ...
```

to unwrap `DaPhone` into an actual *list*.